# how to get result on click using class in resultant "A Tag" javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get result on click using class in resultant "A Tag" javascript?

**For more detail please visit following link:**
      http://jsfiddle.net/0mcdb4th/1/

```
<ul>
   <li><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector category" id="abc" value="abc"/> <label for="abc" tabIndex="-1">abc</label></li>
   <li><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector category" id="def" value="def"/> <label for="def" tabIndex="-1">def</label></li>
</ul>
```

When i click on checkbox then result see in bottom orange tag. then when i will click on orange link then nothing happened in javascript "using classname".

Thanks in advance

Comment: There has to be something in common in order to do that. Right now you have 3 individual id's.

Comment: Can you show us the `Schema::create` of the tables? Also `User` model and `Comment` model. Have you created a relationship?

Comment: Plus `return $this->hasOne('App\User');` should be enough i think

Comment: @AntoniosTsimourtos I think you are writing in wrong page

Comment: PLease check this link : http://jsfiddle.net/0mcdb4th/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating the html dynamically so you need to bind the events for the generated html too, more specifically you can bind the document click, like this.

```
$(document).on("click",".common_selector",function(){
 var state = get_state('category');
 alert('clicked')
})
```

```js
$(document).on("click",".common_selector",function(){
 var state = get_state('category');
 alert('clicked')
})


function get_state(class_name) {
  var statename = [];
  $('.' + class_name + ':checked').each(function() {
    statename.push($(this).val());
  });

  var categoryname = "";
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < statename.length; i++) {
    categoryname += "<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='common_selector category'>" + statename[i] + " <i class='lnr lnr-cross'></i></a>";
  }

  $("#statename").html(categoryname);
  return statename;

}
```

```css
a {
  background: orange;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector category" id="abc" value="abc" /> <label for="abc" tabIndex="-1">abc</label></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="common_selector category" id="def" value="def" /> <label for="def" tabIndex="-1">def</label></li>
</ul>

<div id="statename"></div>
```

Comment: Let me check, Thanks